# Calling events in modular JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, module

I'm only learning how to work with the modules in JavaScript, so I have three separate `.js` files: `main`, `listener` and `fileHandler`

Simply this is a program that for every selected or dropped file(image) from computer gets appended to the page. Functions are working when I drag and drop files to the page, but when I select them through `inputBox` button files even files are stored in `inputBox.files`, they are not getting appended to the page.

```
var uploader = {};

uploader.init = function () {
    this.inputBox = document.getElementById('uploadButton');
    this.dropbox = document.getElementById('dropbox');
    this.listener();
}
```

and listener method as:

probably I'm calling 'change' event wrongly here, that files are not appended.

```
uploader.listener = function () {
    uploader.inputBox.addEventListener('change', uploader.fileHandler.addFiles(uploader.inputBox.files));
    this.dropbox.addEventListener('drop', this.fileHandler.drop.bind(this));
}
```

one another constructor is:

```
uploader.fileHandler = new function () {
    var uploadHandler = function () {...}
    this.addFiles = function (files) {
        Object.keys(files).forEach(function (key) {
            var file = files[key];
            uploadHandler(files[key]);
        });
    };
    this.drop = function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
        this.fileHandler.addFiles(files);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I see another issue.  When you do this:

```
uploader.inputBox.addEventListener('change', uploader.fileHandler.addFiles(uploader.inputBox.files));
```

You are calling `uploader.fileHandler.addFiles(uploader.inputBox.files)` immediately and passing it's return value to `.addEventListener()`.  Probably what you want instead is this:

```
uploader.inputBox.addEventListener('change', function() {  
    uploader.fileHandler.addFiles(uploader.inputBox.files)
});
```

Here you are passing an anonymous function reference which can be called later by the event handler.

---

This construct:

```
uploader.fileHandler = new function () {
    this.addFiles = function (files) {
        Object.keys(files).forEach(function (key) {
            var file = files[key];
            uploadHandler(files[key]);
        });
    };
}
```

only assigns a function to `uploader.fileHandler`.  It does not define `uploader.fileHandler.addFiles` until you actually call that function (which you do not show).

I don't know why you're trying to nest your function definitions (that usually just causes more complexity than benefit in Javascript), but if you really wanted to define them that way, you could do this:

```
uploader.fileHandler = {
    addFiles: function (files) {
        Object.keys(files).forEach(function (key) {
            var file = files[key];
            uploadHandler(files[key]);
        });
    },
    drop: function(...) {...}
};
```

This would then define both of these functions:

```
uploader.fileHandler.addFiles()
uploader.fileHandler.drop()
```

Comment: Everything works fine with drop, when i drop a photo to the `dropbox` element, but image is not getting appended when I choose it from select box `inputBox`

Comment: @developer - same issue.  Until you call `uploader.fileHandler()`, `uploader.fileHandler.addFile` and `uploader.fileHandler.drop` do not exist as they are only created when `uploader.fileHandler()` is executed.  Perhaps you just aren't showing enough of your code for us to follow what is/isn't happening.

Comment: @developer - see the edit I added to the beginning of my answer.

Comment: I was supposed to make the project configurable and to separate it into parts, so if you think that my way is wrong, could you show a way that wouldn't affect the performance.